# Placing a loading screen in laravel while getting data from server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

I'll try to explain. I have a dynamic view that display in a list all the results that my query gets. each element has a "view" button. That button is a get request that handles the action to my controller. The problem is that it takes a long time to bring the info of the element to display its info. I wanna put a loading screen while the GET is finished but I've tried a lot of solutions but none solve my problem .

Here's my route

```
Route::get('/certificaciones/consultar/{id}&{tipo}&{order_id}&{count}', [
    'uses' => 'certificacionesController@preview',
    'as' => '/certificaciones/consultar/vistaPrevia']);
```

i do the calling here

```
<td style="width: 5px;"><a href="{{route('/certificaciones/consultar/vistaPrevia', [$res->id_acta, $tipo, $order_id, $count])}}"><button class="btn btn-xs pink tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Consultar" id="loading"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button></a></td>
```

What i want is when the user click that button, it shows a loading screen while the controller is done getting all data and display the preview blade

I hope I made myself clear and please help me I'm stuck there

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to send your request via ajax.

Make a div having loading icon as gif image. Hide div via css property `display: none;` Just before ajax show the loading div & in success callback hide the loading div.

Alternative, you can show the loading div on `onclick` event of your button & hide the loading div on `document.ready` of view which is going to open.

Don't forget to add `z-index:10000` for loading div in order to keep it on top of everything.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback, I'll try that and get back to u